# Native components communicating directly with each other in ReactNative

Tags: javascript, performance, react-native, native

Lets say that there is a native component `A` which represents an accurate timer without UI. `B` and `C` are native UI components displayed on the screen. Those UI elements are depending on the timer `A` via events.

Is it somehow possible to hook up `B` to `A` and `C` to `A` from react native code (avoiding the Singleton pattern), but in a way that they communicate directly and natively without using the javascript ReactNative bridge? Can I somehow pass the instance of `B` (and its protocol/interface) to `A` trigger from ReactNative?

I had something in mind like

```
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <NativeModuleB nativeTimerModule={this.props.nativeTimerA}/>      
            <NativeModuleC nativeTimerModule={this.props.nativeTimerA}/>      
        </View>
    );
}
```

(Background: I want to reduces latencies as this part of the application has extremely timing critical sections)

[image]